# Ruby app throwing "attempt to pop an unknown release pool"? (OpenGL, OS X)

Tags: ruby, nsautoreleasepool

In my small Ruby project using OpenGL via Gosu and Chingu I'm now seeing a number of these errors pop up during my tests:

> 2011-09-30 23:31:01.789 ruby[832:903] *** attempt to pop an unknown autorelease pool (0x12c55a00)

**UPDATE**: I'm now also seeing some of these forms, definitely indicating a leak:

> 2011-10-01 03:50:00.281 ruby[3212:903] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x461aa0 of class NSCFNumber autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
>
> 2011-10-01 03:50:00.282 ruby[3212:903] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x461ae0 of class NSConcreteValue autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
>
> 2011-10-01 03:50:00.283 ruby[3212:903] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x10ce230 of class NSCFNumber autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
>
> 2011-10-01 03:50:00.285 ruby[3212:903] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x42abb0 of class NSConcreteValue autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
>
> 2011-10-01 03:50:00.286 ruby[3212:903] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0xa031570 of class NSCFDictionary autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking

Any thoughts on what likely causes might be for this? It's somewhat enigmatic message to me -- or at least it doesn't provide enough context for me to immediately diagnose. It doesn't seem to cause any of the tests to fail or anything, but I'm certain I am leaking memory -- probably from not closing a resource down properly, I would guess, but I'm not really sure how to go about tracking this down. Can ruby-debug help me figure out what's going on here? What should my next steps in the investigation here be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This looks related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7189313/runtime-error-nsautoreleasenopool-autoreleased-with-no-pool-in-place-j).  If you are using explicit threading in your application, check to see if you can register the cleanup widget they mention there.  If not, try dusting off the C++ underneath your gem dependency and see if you can't grep it there.